# Is the arithmetic sequence a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a and k be some constants. Is $(a, a+k, a+2k...)$ a subspace of the set of all infinite sequences of real numbers?

My book says it is, but I don't understand why. Let $k>2*a$. Hence, 2a is not within the set, so this set shouldn't be a subspace.

Comment: I think that you didn`t understood question good.I think they want to say that all aritmethmtic arrays are subspace of all real arrays which is easy to prove.

Comment: If you multiply  every element in an arithmetic progression by the same scalar do you get a new arithmetic progression?

Comment: I think yes.i am wrong?

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, but how is that relevant? I thought we need multiplication of any element in the set to be an element of the same set... for the set to be a subspace?

Comment: @LinkingPark The book agrees with you, but I still don't understand why.

Comment: If you add two arithmetic progressions you will get a new one as well (think about it a bit). Piece this together with what Ethan said and you should have a proof.

Comment: @Goldname To be a subset you must have closure when you multiply (the whole sequence) by any _scalar_. Whether or not that scalar is a member of the sequence is irrelevant.

Comment: Don't forget that the elements of the vector space you are working in are sequences of real numbers, and an arithmetic progression is a sequence. You need to show that a sum of two progressions is a progression and that any scalar multiple of a progression is a progression. It seems to me you are thinking that the terms of the progression are the elements you are dealing with, rather than the progressions themselves.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes scaling a sequence means that it is still a sequence, which means that it is still an element of the set of all infinite sequences. However, the set itself is not a subspace of V right?? Because the set does not contain scalar multiples of itself.

Comment: @ChrisLeary I understand the progressions are the elements, but it's asking for which of these subsets are a subspace. Hence, it's asking if the progression is the subspace right?

Comment: I think you've written the question incorrectly. Just the part "Is $(a,a+k,a+2k,\dots)$ a subspace of the set of all infinite sequences $\dots$?" has an immediate negative answer, because $(a,a+k,a+2k,\dots)$ is not a subset but a single element of that set. What is true (and explained by several commenters) is that the **set of all** sequences of the form $(a,a+k,a+2k,\dots)$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Proof sketch/idea.

Let $S$ be the set of all sequences of real numbers. It's a vector space with the obvious (I hope) operations: add corresponding entries, multiply all entries by a scalar.

Let $A$ be the subset of arithmetic progressions.

Is the zero vector in $S$ a member of $A$?

If you add two sequences in $A$ do you get another element of $A$?

If you multiply a sequence in $A$ by a scalar is the result in $A$?